# Get a sum from a Flask Table

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a Flask-Table:

```
# tables.py
from flask_table import Table, Col

class Results(Table):

    id = Col('Id', show=False)
    date = Col('Date')
    parts = Col('Parts')
    car_model = Col('Car Model')
    item_count = Col('Item Count')
    value = Col('Value')
```

In the `app.py` select everything from the table, using SQLAlchemy and I render it to an HTML page using Jinja.

```
# app.py 
@app.route('/sales', methods=['GET', 'POST')
def sales():
    results = Sales.query.order_by(Sales.date).all()
    table = Results(results)
    return render_template('sales.html', table=table)


# sales.html
{{ table }}
```

I want to display a Total row, that will have the sum of values. Is there any way to do that with Flask-Table or do I have to make another SQLAlchemy query? I tried creating a class method inside Results class, but I couldn't make it work.

Bare in mind that I also have a method to search the DB by date and I want to have a total of the filtered table too.

Comment: Make a list comprehension with `results` and sum only fields you need. Ex: `total = sum([sale.field_name for sale in results])`

Comment: are you using sessions by any chance? Then it can done at the db level and you can get total value as the result directly

Comment: No, I'm not using sessions. But could you show me how this will work with sessions? Cause I'm not familiar with it.